# Spring 5 WebClient | Suppress Connection Refused Exception Logging

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

How to suppress logging Connection Refused Exceptions in the following client-sided http call?

```
return WebClient.create("http://anyurl")
    .get()
    .uri(builder -> {
        return builder.path("/somePath")
                .queryParam("...", ...)
                .build();
    })
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToFlux(AnyPojo.class)
    // shouldn't this convert any error in an empty Flux?
    .onErrorResume(e -> Flux.empty())
    .map(this::myMappingMethod)
    .collectList()
    .block();
```

I already applied `onErrorResume()` in the chain but still the error is logged:

```
07:31:51.997 [reactor-http-nio-5] ERROR o.s.web.reactive.function.client - onError(io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: 068933adf361/172.17.0.2:80)
07:31:51.998 [reactor-http-nio-5] ERROR o.s.web.reactive.function.client -
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: 068933adf361/172.17.0.2:80
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:612)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:559)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:476)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Comment: It *does* convert the error to an empty Flux, but it also looks like it's logging it. I can't tell for certain, but it looks like it's logging at ERROR severity; if that's the case, you should probably file a bug, because that's *definitely* not that severe.

Comment: I followed your advise and filed a bug: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16484